# Finding server(s) capacity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, performance, load

I am working on a application stack as follows:

There is a cisco load balancer that can handle 40K concurrent users in front of 2 application server. In the back there is a sql server with 2 TB data.

What i want to find out is how much traffic this application can handle at peak times, in other words what is the capacity of this stack.

I am aware of JMeter. I dont think running jmeter from a single machine can find out the capacity of the application.

How would one determine capacity of this stack?

Comment: Really seems more of an "admin" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont think running jmeter from a single machine can find out the
>   capacity of the application.

JMeter has a [`distributed mode`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) allowing you to simulate huge loads by using multiple client machines:

> In the event that your JMeter client machine is unable,
>   performance-wise, to simulate enough users to stress your server, an
>   option exists to control multiple, remote JMeter engines from a single
>   JMeter GUI client. By running JMeter remotely, you can replicate a
>   test across many low-end computers and thus simulate a larger load on
>   the server. One instance of the JMeter GUI client can control any
>   number of remote JMeter instances, and collect all the data from
>   them.

Comment: While you know the context, i wanna ask you, how can i performance test database? also application such as garbage collection, memory etc. Thanks:)

Comment: There's a plugin for JMeter which allows you to measure various performance counters from your servers: https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon